# custom post template file not shown, instead all the time 404.php

Tags: posts, templates, 404-error, customization

i'm completely confused, want to use my own template file for a custom post type and of course i read all about this here or in the Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates )

Also i found users with the same problem ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461285/what-would-make-a-custom-post-type-template-not-show-up ), and of course i already have updated the permalink page (change the setting > save > change setting to original back > save !). Nothing has worked out so far :( .

What did i done ?

First i register my custom post type as usual with that code:

```
register_post_type( 'series', array(
      'supports'                => array('title', 'editor'),
      'menu_position'           => 20,
      'show_ui'                 => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus'       => false,
      'show_in_menu'            => true,
      'public'                  => true,
      'register_meta_box_cb'    => array($this, 'addMetaBoxes'),
      'public_queryable'        => true,
      'has_archive'             => true
    )
);
```

After the registration i expected to have access to my custom template file, if i create the **single-series.php** template file inside my theme root directory.

But ... boohhh.

All the time my **404.php** is called instead of my desired custom template file... what (the hell) goes wrong ??? Do i forget something important ? ...argghh ! Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try saving permalink settings.

Comment: Did you try with changing permalink structure? Can you send me your site link?

Comment: i've just tried, change the permalink structure to something other and back - no success ! :( What do you mean with 'site link' ??? My custom post type should be accessible by http://mysite.com/series/name-of-the-series ...

Comment: He means the URL to the site - unless you are working locally. Try "disabling" your permalink settings (first option) and try viewing the post. See if it comes up when it goes to `mysite.com/?p=123`

Comment: i'm working locally ... still :/

Comment: wow ... @EricHolmes !!! With the standard setting like `mysite.com/p=123` ... IT WORKS !!! The custom template file is called, but i want to have a custom permalink ?! :/

Comment: Fair enough - it's the smartest way to do it. You can, however, go to ipchicken.com, or something like that, get your external IP, and access the site externally ;) fun fact, but not necessary. Is your post type appearing in the back end, working as normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that it's working without permalinks enabled, try resetting your permalinks back to the way you want them. That full reset *should* work.

Edit: Are you be doing anything funky with the `rewrite` argument?

Comment: Thank you very much Eric, this **full reset** worked out - i don't changed the `rewrite`-argument. What did i done:

 1. I've changed the permalink structure back to `standard` 
 2. Save 
 3. Call a custom post page with the preview function - custom post template file was shown. 
 4. Turn back the permalink settings to your custom settings

Comment: Glad to hear it! What probably happened is you set your permalinks before setting up the post type. I believe that permalink settings need to be changed for it to take into account a new post type (unlike how normally you just need to visit the Permalinks page to update).